# Showing created by user name on OpenERP records

Tags: odoo

On any record/object in OpenERP, such as Journal Voucher, Journal Entry, etc. is there a way to show which user created or posted this record?

I would like to show this on the record itself when we open the detail view. Ideally this should also be visible in the search grids.

The audit trail feature lets you view it in a separate area and it captures a lot more detail, but I would like to capture and show only the user name who worked on a record.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use write_uid, create_uid and for that you have to override those fields in your model.

 You can even make related field for name.

```
_columns = {
    'create_uid': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Created By', readonly=True),
    'creator_name': fields.related("create_uid", "name", type="char", string="Creator Name"),
    'write_uid': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Modified By'),
    'write_name': fields.related("write_uid", "name", type="char", string="Moderator Name"),
}
```

Here, create_uid must be "readonly=True" otherwise you will face an error while saving a record.

Comment: Thanks. Can I do this without overriding? I mean through View Manager window?

Comment: It means you want to make changes direct from gtk/web client?
If yes then may be you can but not sure. I would suggest you should make changes in .py and .xml files.

Comment: I finally got back to this task, but it is not working. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741401/openerp-customizing-journal-voucher-view