# OpenERP customizing Journal Voucher view

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to do a simple customization that is not working for some odd reason:

**init**.py:

```
import account_voucher_hash
```

**openerp**.py

```
{
"name" : "Hash Voucher",
"version" : "1.1",
"depends" : [
              'base',
              'account_voucher',
            ],
"author" : "me",
"description": """The Module customizes Vouchers""",

'website': 'http://abc.com',
'init_xml': [],
'update_xml': [
    'account_voucher_view_hash.xml',
],
'demo_xml': [],
'installable': True,
'active': False,
}
```

**account_voucher_hash.py**

```
from osv import fields, osv
import netsvc

class account_voucher_hash(osv.osv):
_name = 'account.voucher'
_inherit = 'account.voucher'
_columns={
          'test1': fields.integer('Test 1'),
          'create_uid': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Created By'),
          'creator_name': fields.related("create_uid", "name", type="char", string="Creator Name"),
          'write_uid': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Modified By'),
          'write_name': fields.related("write_uid", "name", type="char", string="Modifier Name"),
          }
account_voucher_hash()
```

**account_voucher_view_hash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
 <data>

    <record id="view_voucher_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">account_voucher_hash_form</field>
        <field name="model">account.voucher</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="15"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account_voucher.view_voucher_form" />
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="reference" select="2" position="after">
                    <field name="test1"/>
                    <field name="create_uid"/>
                    <field name="creator_name"/>
                    <field name="write_uid"/>
                    <field name="write_name"/>
                </field>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>


  </data>
</openerp>
```

The Journal Voucher form does not show the new fields.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I have updated my answer in your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602535/showing-created-by-user-name-on-openerp-records/13603444#13603444

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove create_uid and creator_name from .py:

```
_columns = {
    'test1': fields.integer('Test 1'),
    'create_uid': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Created By', readonly=True),
    'creator_name': fields.related("create_uid", "name", type="char", string="Creator Name"),
    'write_uid': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Modified By'),
    'write_name': fields.related("write_uid", "name", type="char", string="Modifier Name"),
}
```

"create_uid" must be readonly.

Try this code in your .xml:

```
<record id="view_voucher_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">account_voucher_hash_form</field>
    <field name="model">account.voucher</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="15"/>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="account_voucher.view_voucher_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="reference" select="2" position="after">
                <field name="test1"/>
                <field name="create_uid"/>
                <field name="creator_name"/>
                <field name="write_uid"/>
                <field name="write_name"/>
            </field>
        </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Tried, no change. I pasted your first snippet into the py file and the second into the xml file. I hope that's what you intended.

Comment: It's working fine to me. Just restart the server and update the module, then go to Account/Journal Entries/Journal Voucher. There you can see your fields.

Comment: That did work! Thanks a bunch. Can you please indicate what was the issue?

Comment: Problem was in your xml. Just compare your xml code & my given code of xml. Second thing is that "create_uid" field must be "readonly=True" otherwise it will give error when you will create a record.